# Connect to Mongo DB cluster

Tags: mongodb

I can execute `Mongo` in Command but I can`t execute the command to connect to the mongoDB cluster and
with mongoshell

what`s the problem.....

Mongo atlas⇒Clusters connect ⇒connect with mongo shell⇒ mongo shell version is correct

⇒Run your connection string in your command line⇒

⇒ `mongo "mongodb+srv://xxxx.xxxxxxx/<dbname>" --username xxxxx`

Then I have error...
what's the `<dbname>`? do I have to make a folder? where?

```
FailedToParse: Database name cannot have reserved characters for mongodb:// URL: mongodb+srv://xxxxxxx/
try 'mongo --help' for more information
```

Comment: Welcome! If you're trying to connect to MongoDB Atlas, they should have instructions that provide you with your database name (something you specify when you create your MongoDB Database) and full connection string (including the credentials you created). There are no folders with MongoDB. And the `<` and `>` characters should not actually be included in the command-line; they are just there to give you a hint that it's a field you have to replace (e.g. if your database name is `mydatabase` then replace `<dbname>` with `mydatabase`, not `<mydatabase>`.

Comment: It worked perfectly!!! Even If I didn`t have the database name,I tried to connect to "test" as default. Finally I can proceed with the next step. Very helpful!!!!!Thank you!!!